# Binding double to android:text

Tags: android, android-databinding

Using two way data binding I'm trying to fit a double(Double) inside a EditText type field.

I have tried with converter functions (with @InverseMethod) and also tried to write a @BindingAdapter with @InverseBindingAdapter.

I think I may be missing something crucial cause:

```
"@={`` + muObject.myDecimal}"
```

reveals 'null' in the EditText field.

The @InverseFunction method crashes, and the binding adapter way did not work either...

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

ViewModel code:
Note that the BaseObservableViewModel extends ViewModel from architecture components and contains the contents of the BaseObservable class (tip from Yigit Boyar).

Also note that none of the fields in the QualityControl class are observable.

At last: Note that the getter/setter for measurementKm are a test. measurementKm is Double field in the QualityControl class and I would prefer to bind directly to that field.

```
public final class QualityControlViewModel extends BaseObservableViewModel {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = "QualityControlVM";

private QualityControl qualityControl;
private int position;



public String measurementKm = "";


QualityControlViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
}

public QualityControl getQualityControl() {
    return qualityControl;
}

public void setQualityControl(QualityControl qualityControl) {
    this.qualityControl = qualityControl;

    // Initialize massMeasurementPlaceSelected
    if (isValidMassMeasurementPlace()) massMeasurementPlaceSelected = true;
    setMeasurementKm(qualityControl.getMeasurementKm());
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}

private Double getMeasurementKm() {
    if (this.measurementKm.length() > 0) {
        return Double.parseDouble(this.measurementKm);
    } else {
        return 0.0;
    }
}

private void setMeasurementKm(Double measurementKm) {
    if (qualityControl.getMeasurementKm() != null) {
        this.measurementKm = String.valueOf(qualityControl.getMeasurementKm());
    }
    notifyChange();
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you try String.valueOf(muObject.myDecimal)

Comment: But... what exactly are you trying to do? They way to wrote your code, when you type in the EditText, you are going to write in the muObject.myDecimal... is it what you are trying to do?

Comment: In addition to what Leandro has asked, can you show the code of your ViewModel? If you are doing a two-way binding, are you using an ObservableField?

Comment: @WoogieNoogie: No. I am extending BaseObservable. Will post the code now.

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira: String.valueOf will only work with one way data binding, or am I mistaken?
Yes. I Wan't to write directly back to my model.